# Book recommendation for: Introduction to Health, Anthropology, Demography. History of Medicine

Tags: health-education, medical-history, social-anthropology

Could you recommend a book for this subject on medicine: Introduction to Health, Anthropology, Demography. History of Medicine?

The thematic blocks of the subject are:

**1. Health and healthcare system:**
 - The medical profession: basic concepts
 - Medical-patient relationship
 - Determinants of health
 - Preventive measures for students: vaccinations
 - How is a primary care center organized?
 - National Health Services in the European Union
 - The healthcare system
 - Medical specialties: the MIR system
 - The health of the world
 - Confidentiality and data protection: practical aspects
 - How to prepare a work and make a presentation
 - How is the Faculty of Medicine organized?
 - Practices in the primary health care center (PHCC)
 - Basic First Aid Practices (RCP)
 - Hand hygiene practices

**2. History of medicine and medical anthropology**
 - Historic evolution of the medical profession
 - Basic history of medicine

**3. Health demography**
 - Introduction to demography
 - Registers and CIM classifications
 - Structure of the population
 - Mortality
 - Migrations and health
 - Natality and growth. Projections
 - Standardization methods
 - Demographic and epidemiological transition
 - Premature and avoidable mortality
 - Direct standardization
 - Indirect standardization
 - Premature and avoidable mortality

Thanks

Comment: That certainly looks like a college or med school course description. Why not just buy the book(s) the course is using?

Comment: In my experience I do not think you will find a single book that contains all the above. One for each is more likely. It looks like you're copying forward a syllabus for a course; were there no book recommendations given?

Comment: I agree with @DoctorWhom as each section has huge subjects which can lead to volumes of information, especially section 2 with how amputations were performed before anaesthesia was developed, then the different forms of anaesthesia over time, wound management before penicillin and how they prevented and treated "fever sickness" when they didn't even know about germs.... Very big subjects.